# Python Regex checking for repeated combination

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a file that has asterisks (*) and pipes (|).

I would like a regex to match a combination where there are at least 4 pipes with any number of asterisks between them. Any number of pipes need to be matched as long as there are at least 4.

I need to be able to remove these from the file, leaving everything else intact.

**Examples:**

Matches:

```
   |||||||||||||||

   |***|*||******|  

   |||*****************|
```

Does Not Match:

```
   |||

   |?|*|*|

   |||?|
```

Comment: You can test your regex here: http://regexr.com/ . There is also a useful regex cheatsheet.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```regex
(?:[*]*[|]){4,}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Find substrings that are made up `*` and `|` characters
- Requires the substring to contain at least four `|` characters
- Allows the substring to have any number of `*` characters

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/mJ4nY4/2

**Sample text**

```
|||||||||||||||
|***|*||******|
|||*****************|
|||
|?|*|*|
|||?|
```

**Sample Matches**

```
|||||||||||||||
|***|*||******|
|||*****************|
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (at least 4
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [*]*                     any character of: '*' (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [|]                      any character of: '|'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){4,}                    end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

## Alternate

If you do not want to capture the a leading `*` as in the string `*|||**|` then you could use this expression

```
[|](?:[*]*[|]){3,}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/yN6wK2/1